# Search and Select multiple items from Excel filter results

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I want to be able to **deselect all values** from the excel filter and just search for a value and select the checkbox as I go.

But when I search for a user + select it and search for another one it doesn't remember my previous selection. I.e. it can only search and show one user at the time.

I do not want to scroll through the fields and select them one by one...

How do I search and select multiple users on an 'as I go' method?

Answer (score 3):

It's quite simple and built in - here is the procedure

```
 1. Filter on your first selection
 2. Search for your next value and select it
 3. Also select "add current selection to filter"
 4. Press OK
 5. Repeat from 2
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can't do what you're describing. If you want to see all instances of a set of keywords, you can create a list and use the Advanced Filter function, but that's slightly different than what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 : click on the filter

step 2: paste the text in the search
box then after the list has been filtered, click on "add to current
selection"then click OK

step 3 : after the result has been filtered,
repeat the operation :

[image]